# Why is the AuthType function being skipped on my Community Connector?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm using the following code for the authentication (which I took from a sample code that works, I only changed the URL 
 on checkForValidKey() )

```
function getAuthType() {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
  .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.KEY)
  .setHelpUrl('https://helpdesk.e-goi.com/858130-O-que-%C3%A9-a-API-do-E-goi-e-onde-est%C3%A1-a-API-key')
  .build();
}

function resetAuth() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.key');
}

function isAuthValid() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var key = userProperties.getProperty('dscc.key');
  return checkForValidKey(key);
}

function setCredentials(request) {
  var key = request.key;
  var validKey = checkForValidKey(key);
  if (!validKey) {
    return {
      errorCode: 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS'
    };
  }
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('dscc.key', key);
  return {
    errorCode: 'NONE'
  };
}

function checkForValidKey(key) {
  var token = key;
 var url = [
    'http://api.e-goi.com/v2/rest.php?method=getUserData&type=json&functionOptions[apikey]=',
    key
  ];
  var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow',
        muteHttpExceptions: true
        };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.join(''),requestOptions);
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

But once I run the community connector, it seems to skip all these functions and go straight to the getConfig() part, which stops me from proceeding on my connector because I need to input an API Key to get my data. An interesting observation is that if I remove the query part of the url (so url = https://api.e-goi.com/v2/rest.php), the AuthType input is triggered when I run the connector. This is no good though, because that url doesn't lead anywhere and so the API key authentication fails.

**What causes this and how can I fix this?** I've found a workaround, which is asking for the API key on the getConfig, but this is not the correct way to do it, and I need to do it via getAuthType to get my Community Connector verified.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Goto datastudio.google.com.
2. Click Create > Data Source.
3. From the 'Partner Connector' list, find your connector. Click on the vertical ellipses on the top right of the connector card and click 'Revoke Access'.
4. Try authorizing your connector again.

Comment: I did this but it didn't work. Still no getAuthType input :/

Comment: Can you add logging to `getAuthType` and see if it gets called?

Comment: Yes the authtype runs and gets logged in the Stackdriver Logger but it seems that it runs very quickly (0.7 seconds) and then goes straight to getConfig

Comment: I have this issue as well, any luck?
I do notice one with wrong with your code though, should be: cc.AuthTypes.KEY I believe